# CROSS APPLY issue - filtering a many-to-one relationship

Tags: sql-server, performance, cross-apply

I have found an issue with how MS SQL Server handles `CROSS APPLY`.

The database I'm working with has a pricing system with the following schema:

> Service -> Price Model <- Price Component (*'->' indicates a Foreign Key pointing to the table*)

Some price models have "stepped pricing", which means when an amount parameter reaches various thresholds, the price will increase (1-3 units is price A, 4-8 units is price B, etc.).

The problem I'm having is that an `INNER JOIN` between [Service] and [Price Component] on [Price Model ID] is producing duplicate rows, since I'm not actually using the prices in the Price Component, just another field in the table that is the same for each of the [Price Component] rows.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM [Service] s
 INNER JOIN [Price Component] pc
    ON s.[Price Model Id] = pc.[Price Model Id]
```

The logical fix for this issue is to replace the `INNER JOIN` with a `CROSS APPLY` that does this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM [Service] s
 CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 * 
                FROM [Price Component] pc
               WHERE s.[Price Model Id] = pc.[Price Model Id]
             ) AS pc
```

The problem is that the efficiency is utterly destroyed in some other joins seemingly unrelated to this change. Looking at the execution plan, a join that used to take 2.3 cycles now takes 4.8 million cycles.

I have tried adding a `DISTINCT` to the original query (since it doesn't use unique data from the [Price Component] table, and this is a function solution except that it quadruples the run time.  I have also tried returning just the value I need from the [Price Component] table, but it doesn't seem to help much:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM [Service] s
 CROSS APPLY (SELECT DISTINCT pc.moneyUnitId 
                FROM [Price Component] pc
               WHERE s.[Price Model Id] = pc.[Price Model Id] 
             ) AS pc
```

Strangely, changing the `CROSS APPLY` to an `OUTER APPLY` fixes the issues with the other joins, but defeats the purpose of the CROSS APPLY (which, as I understand it, is basically the difference between an `INNER JOIN` and an `OUTER JOIN`).

Does anyone have any thoughts or insights on what might be causing the insane increase in complexity with the `CROSS APPLY`?

**UPDATE**

So after reading some more about how to interpret an execution plan, I've learned the following:

- Original Query (using `INNER JOIN`s) is a long series of Nested Loops
  that starts with whatever filter data you give it.  Pretty snappy
  response times as long as filter is on indexed fields.
- Modified Query (using `CROSS APPLY`) is a longer series of Hash
  Matches, and joins every table you give it except the ones with
  filters, then applies the filters last.  Always slower than death.
- Working Modified query (with `OUTER APPLY`), does the same thing as the
  original, but doesn't exclude results that don't match up with the
  WHERE clause.  Just as snappy as the original.

So the issue is: why does a `CROSS APPLY` make the plan change to join all tables before the requested filter?

Comment: Can you post the execution plans?

Comment: Unfortunately no... the original plan is far too large to get a screenshot, and has proprietary info I can't share anyway. I've tried constructing a minimal version that just includes the main offending tables, and the issue doesn't seem to be occurring.  I'm going to try removing joins in the original until I find which once is causing it to blow up.

Comment: Presumably changing the query alters the cardinality estimates in some way hence the different join strategies?

Comment: Can you please post the schema for this table?  Are the keys strings or integers?  Hash Match join should be optimal here iff it's an integer key and you can re-write the query to be a semijoin reduction.

Answer (score 1):

Why not:

```
select t1.colA, t3.colX from table1 t1
inner join (select distinct t2.t1FK, t2.colX from table2 t2) t3 on t1.ID = t3.t1FK
```

Answer (score 0):

IF the execution plans are not identical between the `JOIN` and `CROSS APPLY`, then the query optimizer is using the Nested Loops logical operator which in some circumstances can negatively affect performance. See here for some basic info on Nested Loops: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191318(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: I have found a better summary of my question... please read the end of my original post.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only using one field from the table with the one-many have you considered using group by and max() to filter the records?

```
select a.field1, a.field2, max(b.field3)
from table1 a
join table2 b on a.someid = b.someid
group by a.field1, a.field2
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the query is much too complex to use aggregates, and it's not really necessary in my case anyway.  The data I'm using from the [Price Component] table is basically switching between USD and CAD (US Dollars/Canadian Dollars), and for any given [Price Model], the [Price Component] values will have the same value for the data I want.

Comment: Basically what I'm concerned now with is why the CROSS APPLY makes the execution plan decide to join all the values in the tables before filtering, and the INNER JOIN and OUTER APPLY do not.